# Advanced C++: Copy configuration (object) in a template template class's instance

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-templates

I have a problem with templatized classes that I made most abstract with this example.

So for a class which has the form

```
template <typename T, template <typename T> class MyFunctor>
class MyMainClass
{
    MyFunctor<T> myInstance;
public:
    setConfigOfMyFunctor<ConfigClass>(const ConfigClass& cfg); //problem is here. How can I write this?
}
```

I define FunctorClass which I will use as the second template parameter in MyMainClass

```
template <typename T>
class FunctorClass
{
public:
    ConfigClass<T> cfg;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

where my config class is simply

```
template <Typename T>
class ConfigClass
{
    T cfgval1;
    T cfgval2;
public:
    void setVals(int cfgVal1, ...);
    //.....
}
```

If I make an object of this class

```
int main()
{
    typedef double T;
    MyMainClass<T,FunctorClass> classy;
    ConfigClass<T> config;
    config.setVals(1, 2, ...);
    //so I'm looking for something like the following line (taken from first declaration)
    classy.setConfigOfMyFunctor<ConfigClass>(config); //this is supposed to copy the object config to the FunctorClass's object in MyMainClass.
}
```

So in brief, I want the object `config` to be copied to MyMainClass<>::FunctorClass<>::cfg

Is that possible?

If you need more information on the problem, please let me know.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: You could, for example, provide a `typedef` in `FunctorClass` and then write the function as `void setConfigOfMyFunctor(typename MyFunctor<T>::ConfigClass const& cfg);`, or alternatively use a function template `template<class U> void setConfigOfMyFunctor(U const&);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't parametrize `setConfigOfMyFunctor` with any type since you already know type of accepted config - `ConfigClass<T>`.

So you should be able to do it like that:

```
template <typename T, template <typename T> class MyFunctor>
class MyMainClass
{
    MyFunctor<T> myInstance;
public:
    template<template <typename T> class Config>
    setConfigOfMyFunctor(const Config<T>& cfg) {
        myInstance.cfg = cfg;
    }
}
```

(you'll need to add keyword `typename` somewhere (before `Config<T>`, most likely) if compiler asks you to)

Comment: The Config class can be different for every MyFunctor class... sorry this doesn't work.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, okay, then you need templated method, see corrected code.